# Error while executing command: npm run build reason exit status 137 in AWS Code Build

Tags: aws-codebuild

[webpack.Progress] 92% sealing asset processing TerserPlugin
sh: line 1:   241 Killed                  npm run webpack-build
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 137
npm ERR! react-csr-boilerplate@1.0.0 build: `npm run delete-build && npm run webpack-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 137
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-csr-boilerplate@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-04-12T10_10_50_513Z-debug.log

[Container] 2022/04/12 10:10:50 Command did not exit successfully npm run build exit status 137
[Container] 2022/04/12 10:10:50 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2022/04/12 10:10:50 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm run build. Reason: exit status 137
[Container] 2022/04/12 10:10:50 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2022/04/12 10:10:50 Running command echo Build finished on `date`
Build finished on Tue Apr 12 10:10:50 UTC 2022

[Container] 2022/04/12 10:10:50 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2022/04/12 10:10:50 Phase context status code:  Message: